# Magento multi store - Font-face not working in firefox and ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, magento, firefox, font-face

I have Magento Multi store.
  I have loaded the font family using Font-face kit.
  The Font face family is not working in firefox and IE.

**Code:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'zrnicregular';
    src: url('../fonts/zrnic_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/zrnic_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/zrnic_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/zrnic_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/zrnic_rg-webfont.svg#zrnicregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

Main Store URL : firststore.com
Secondary store URL : secondstore.com.
```

This font-face works fine in my main store in all browser.
But in Secondary store font is not loaded correctly in **Firefox and IE**
I'm using same theme for both store.

Help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your secondary domain, your stylesheets are loaded from the first domain, so the fonts get blocked on IE and Firefox due to cross-domain policies.
Add this in your htaccess to allow your secondary website to use the fonts from the first one :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

blmage's solution using htaccess did not work for me, but put me on the right track to solve it:

On your secondary domain:

1) Upload your fonts to: http://www.seconddomain.com/fonts/

2) Update your @font-face reference, e.g.

> @font-face {
>       font-family: 'newfont';
>       src: url('http://www.seconddomain.com/fonts/newfont.eot');
>   }